# How do I access company files using VPN?

Tags: vpn

I am logging into my company's network using the Cisco VPN client. I can see that I am connected but I cannot find any place to access my files in the actual network.

I do have the machine-name with me as well.

How do I get to the company files after the VPN is established?

Comment: Did you make ping to the machine that are you trying to access? I yes and the ping is successful. If you are in a Windows network. Do you have privileges for write in the remote machine?

Comment: You need to RDP into your work system and then figure out the links.

Comment: Go and ask your computer department, they configured your company's network and can tell you about how to access your files.